# Using the Output JSON data returned from a nested Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Im creating a POC with nested Step Functions (SF) and have hit the following issue.

- I have SF A that has a sync task that starts the execution of SF B (using the [recently announced syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html)) & waits for it to complete.
- SF B returns a valid JSON output
- In SF A, I can see (from the output of the task that calls SF B) the correct fields returned. e.g Status, ExecutionArn as well as the Output.
- I then want to execute a Choice Task in SF A that uses a field returned from SF B. However the json in the Output field returned from SF B is escaped json, so the jsonPath isn't able to extract a field from the output data from the nested json.

Is there something im missing or a recommended approach to this scenario? I could "process" the escaped json string in a lambda or something but using it in the Choice task... but that kinda defeats the point of the nested SF workflow somewhat.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm building some nested workflows and the same problem exists.  I can make an ECS activity that parses the string, but that just feels gross.

Comment: No im afraid not. We were evaluating Step Functions at the time and didn't take it any further

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I put in a support ticket asking about it, and their response said that it was a known feature request, and that it was on the roadmap, although they couldn't give me a release date.

Comment: @mbragg02 agree it is less than ideal but for now it seems the best way to parse outputs between step functions is to use a lambda.

Otherwise, perhaps store the outputs (maybe you want to persist this information for audit purposes anyway) in a dynamodb which links to the execution id and then you can read that between steps?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure it's new since you asked the question but the answer is in the link you provided:
Use "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2" in the task resource field instead of "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync"

[image: state output type table]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Version 2 of the `startExecution` integration (`arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2`) outputs JSON instead of an escaped string. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I used "OutputPath": "$.Output" at first and that returned the escaped json. I removed that and added "ResultPath": "$.Output", This works, it returns the output as json including the escaped version. Its ok for now until AWS addresses this.